# Find related value in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with IDs, names and flags.

I want to create a new column, where related IDs would be filled in.

Here are some rules:

- If the flag = '0' or 'A', then there is no related id
- If the flag = 'B' we need to find the same name (minus the flag in name) but with flag 'A' and get the id
- If the flag = 'C' we need to find the same name (minus the flag in name) but with flag 'B' and get the id

Here is the code for the DF:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name': ['test1 A', 'test1 B', 'test2 A', 'test2 B', 'test3','test4 A','test4 B','test4 C'],
     'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     'flag': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', '0', 'A', 'B', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And this is the desired result:

```
name        id     flag    related id
test1 A      1        A           nan
test1 B      2        B           1
test2 A      3        A           nan
test2 B      4        B           3
test3 0      5        0           nan
test4 A      6        A           nan
test4 B      7        B           6
test4 C      8        C           7
```

I was thining about removing the flag from the name and then somehow use groupby or merge, but have fallen short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` with `shift`

```
df['related id']=df.groupby(df.name.str.split().str[0]).id.shift()
df
Out[11]: 
      name  id flag  related id
0  test1 A   1    A         NaN
1  test1 B   2    B         1.0
2  test2 A   3    A         NaN
3  test2 B   4    B         3.0
4    test3   5    0         NaN
5  test4 A   6    A         NaN
6  test4 B   7    B         6.0
7  test4 C   8    C         7.0
```

Comment: this looks good! so I assume it is imperative that the dataframe is sorted by name since we're just shifting the index? or how does groupby handle that?